# Получить значения слайдера

Tags: html, jquery, css

Использую готовую библиотеку слайдера http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/

Ниже показано как у себя реализовал

```
    <input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" />

<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            grid:true,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    from: 1,
    to: 5,
    step: 1,
    onFinish: function (data) {


        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax/searchResult',
                data : {                    

                    'min':data.from,
                    'max':data.to,
                    form

                },                              
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(answer) {             

                }
            });




    }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Я инициализирую слайдер, указываю параметры. Есть Callback функция onFinish которая срабатывает после того как отпустишь слайдер. В data Хряняться значение min и max слайдера. Все работает. Но у меня вопрос, как получить значение min и max слайдера с другого событие, например ввода информацию другого input. Можно получить так `$('#range').val()` но он возвращает значения в формате `2;5`. Как можно нормально получить значения или нужно парсить полученный формат?

Answer (score 1):

изменить положение ползунков и нажать кнопку для получения нового значения

```js
 (function($) {
   $(function() {
     var $range = $("#range");
     $range.ionRangeSlider({
       type: "double",
       grid: true,
       min: 1,
       max: 50,
       from: 1,
       to: 5
     });
     $range = $range.data("ionRangeSlider");
     $("#test").on({
       click: function() {
         var res = $range.result;
         res = [res.from, res.to];
         alert(JSON.stringify(res))
       }
     })
   })
 })(jQuery);
```

```css
.irs {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinNice.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="range" name="range" value="" />
<input id="test" name="" type="button" value="go">
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как ответа не долждался сделал с помощью обрезки, т.к. знаю что конкретно у меня будет возвращать. Этот способ не будет работать с двухзначными числами.

```
var range = $("#range").val();
            var min = range.substr(0,1);
            var max = range.substr(2,1);
```